# Yii Application sso implement

Tags: yii, single-sign-on

this is my first post. I am newbie in Yii framework.

I had tested Yii for a week and I would like to know with Single Sign-On ( SSO )

Example:

I had developed 2 web application like yii app and non-yii.

- test.php // simple login authentication php page and non-yii application
- localhost/onlinetest  // yii application

when I login user authen to "test.php" , I will auto login to "localhost/onlinetest"
and when I logout somewhere in 2 domains . It's logout 2 domains.

any one can help me. thanks
sorry for my english. Thank You

Comment: Maybe you rather want to participate in [this existing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251388/yii-implementing-sso) question?

Comment: I required a solution for that.. if you know that help me. thanks..